# Swift - Custom button class shadow size scaling not working

Tags: swift, button, constraints, scale, shadow

I've wrote this custom button class

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

override func awakeFromNib() {

    layer.cornerRadius = 5

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath

    layer.contents = center
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}
}
```

On my iPhone X everything perfectly fits

[image]

But when I'm using a device with smaller screen, the shadow don't scale correctly according to the button size.

[image]

Is there a problem with the button class itself or is it a constraints problem? I can't find a solution.

Comment: `layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath`. The issue is there. When the `awakeFromNib()` is called, the `bounds` is the one from the Xib. But, after some point, your button gets resize to adapt to the screen (I guess). So the `bounds` did change, but not the `layer.shadowPath`. You can override `var frame`, and use a `didSet{}` to reset again the `layer.shadowPath` to the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the shadow on layoutSubviews (this should also resolve issues your code seemed to have with rotation).

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateShadow(on: self)
    }

func updateShadow(on background: UIView) {
    let layer = background.layer
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: background.bounds).cgPath
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 4
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.22
}

override func awakeFromNib() {

    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    layer.contents = center
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: It works. I've changed the shadowPath to this. `layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: background.bounds, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath` to get the shadow rounded like the buttons.

Comment: Did you use the line you've added in the comment in updateShadow? What difference does that make (sorry for asking, I want to learn).

Comment: Yes to the updateShadow. Without this code the shadow will be rectangular and not rounded like the button.